# Granting permission to the service account

Tags: sql-server, permissions, security, service-accounts

I am currently granting permissions to a service account on a database. I want to ensure if the granting `db_datareader` and `db_datawriter` database roles is the same as my grant command.

Adding service account to `db_datareader` and `db_datawriter` database roles.

```
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'DB_DATAREADER', N'INT\svc-w-corerefdata-de';
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'DB_DATAWRITER', N'INT\svc-w-corerefdata-de';
```

Creating a role, granting permissions to it and adding the service account to the role.

```
IF DATABASE_PRINCIPAL_ID('AlterPermCoreRefData') IS NULL
    BEGIN 
        CREATE ROLE [AlterPermCoreRefData] AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
    END

GRANT EXECUTE, ALTER, SELECT, DELETE, INSERT, UPDATE ON database::[CoreReferenceStaging] TO [AlterPermCoreRefData]

EXEC sp_addrolemember 'AlterPermCoreRefData', 'INT\svc-w-corerefdata-de'
```

Comment: Neither db_datareader nor db_datawriter includes the ALTER or EXECUTE permissions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/database-level-roles

Comment: I basically need the service account to create tables in the database, insert records, truncate records, update records, execute storeprocedures and be able to connect to the database. What is the best and minimum way to achieve that

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the [fixed db roles](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189121(v=sql.110).aspx) in SQL server:

In your first example (`db_datareader` and `db_datawriter`), the service account can only read and modify data in the tables.  With these 2 roles, the service account cannot modify the tables or perform and DDL.  Nor does it have `EXECUTE` permissions.

In your second example, you've given all the permissions above but you've added `EXECUTE` and `ALTER`.  This allows that account to execute SPs and also modify objects (structurally, or otherwise) within the DB.

So, to answer your question, no, they are not the same.  The second example has more permissions and can do more.

Comment: I basically need the service account to create tables in the database, insert records, truncate records,, update records, execute storeprocedures and be able to connect to the database. What is the best and minimum way to achieve that

Comment: The second option